# Django - query an existing database with no keys

Tags: python, sql, django

New to Django.

I have a database that I am connecting to using the multiple database configurations. The tables from one database are obtained using the:

```
$ ./manage.py inspectdb --database=db_name > your_app/models.py
```

The models are:

```py
class Orders(models.Model):
    OrderID = models.IntegerField()
    OrderDate = models.DateTimeField()
    CustomerID = models.IntegerField()

class Customers(models.Model):
    CustomerName= models.CharField(maxlength=200)
    CustomerID = models.IntegerField()
```

There are no keys on the tables and I cannot change them.

Lets say the tables are **Orders** and **Customers** and data can be returned by SQL:

```sql
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

What is the best approach in Django to query tables where I need to specify a join?

Comment: Post your Orders and Customers Django models as well.

Comment: django supports raw sql commands. check out this part of the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Hi Heath, that's very interesting. 
So I create a model that represents the SQL query result fields:

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    birth_date = models.DateField(...)

Then execute custom SQL like so:

>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print(p)
John Smith
Jane Jones

**Considering table joins are a massive part of databases is this a common approach in Django?**